# Unity broken after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: unity

I have upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 using the system updater an now unity is broken.

It looks like a display problem. The icons and the title bar are all messed up and when I try to open the dash the dash window is unintelligible, looks like a television set on a dead channel.

I have to say that the upgrade failed while trying to copy libwekitgtk. I solved that downloading the library manually and that looks OK now.

I have already tried many apt-get update, upgrades, reinstalling unity and. I always get messages that my system is fully updated. It doesn't look like a missing package problem.

Update: if I try doing

```
unity --replace
```

from a shell I get a bunch of these messages:

```
radeon: The kernel rejected CS, see dmesg for more information
```

Thanks for the help.

Giulio

Answer (score 0):

14.04 is out maybe you should try upgrading to that. If that doesn't fix the problem i would do a fresh install of 14.04, there should be an option to keep all the files, programs and settings.

Comment: Actually I did the upgrade very recently starting from 13.04. So I upgraded first to 13.10, noticed the problem but moved on to 14.04 thinking that that would solve the problem. It didn't.
I think it is a problem with the driver for the graphic board. The funny thing is that the problem is only limited to unity and the launcher. The application windows are perfect.